# SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to create a package called helloworld that print out a message

```
cd ~/ro2_ws/src
ros2 pkg create --build-type ament_python helloworld
```

Inside helloworld/helloworld/nodefile.py

```
def main():
    print('Hello world')
```

Inside helloworld/setup.py

from setuptools import setup

```
package_name = 'helloworld'

setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=[package_name],
    data_files=[
        ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages',
                ['resource/' + package_name]),
        ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']),
    ],
    install_requires=['setuptools'],
    zip_safe=True,
    maintainer='TODO',
    maintainer_email='TODO',
    description='TODO: Package description',
    license='TODO: License declaration',
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'nodefile = helloworld.nodefile:main'
        ],
    },
)
```

I try to compile it

```
colcon build --packages-select helloworld
```

I get

```
--- stderr: helloworld                   
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
---
Finished <<< helloworld [0.76s]

Summary: 1 package finished [0.93s]
  1 package had stderr output: helloworld
```

So what is going on

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/396439/setuptoolsdeprecationwarning:-setup.py-install-is-deprecated.-use-build-and-pip-and-other-standards-based-tools./) by [Hairy ass](https://answers.ros.org/users/97281/hairy-ass/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2022-02-19

Post score: 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*Solved it*.
Problem is because of a package utilized by ros2 python packages -> **setuptools**

**Solution**

- python version **3.8**
- setup tools version **58.2.0** ( last version to work with ros2 python packages without any warnings)

---

1 - find out your setup tools version

- In terminal start python

[image: image description]

if it is above 58.2.0 then down grade it

- `pip install setuptools==58.2.0`
  ( all above versions do not work )

now colcon build it .

2 - Make sure you have underscores in **setup.cfg** file and not the '-' .

---

Originally posted by [noshluk2](https://answers.ros.org/users/50994/noshluk2/) with karma: 306 on 2022-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 27

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on 2023-01-02**:
Can I do the same if I'm using ROS2 Humble which uses Python 3.10.6? I just need to downgrade the setuptools version to 58.2.0?

**Comment by [ma ar](https://answers.ros.org/users/135176/ma-ar/) on 2023-01-29**:
Setuptools version 58.2.0 is the last version that works with ROS 2 python packages without any warnings because it is the last version that supports the old installation method, "python setup.py install." This method has been deprecated and replaced by newer, standards-based tools, such as pip and ament.

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2023-02-16**:
It worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04 with ROS2 Humble.

**Comment by [Zac Zhuo Zhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/148260/zac-zhuo-zhang/) on 2023-05-09**:
thanks for the solutions

**Comment by [Mehdi_gh](https://answers.ros.org/users/148398/mehdi_gh/) on 2023-05-10**:
I downgraded setuptools to 58.2.0 but I still get the same error when I run colcon build
What do I need to do to fix it?

**Comment by [noshluk2](https://answers.ros.org/users/50994/noshluk2/) on 2023-05-10**:
Show the error @mehdi

**Comment by [Nils Heidemann](https://answers.ros.org/users/151762/nils-heidemann/) on 2023-05-30**:
Worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04 with ROS2 Humble and Python Version 3.10.6
Just downgrade the setuptools.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This issue seems to be coming from ROS2 directly calling setup.py when building your package (which became deprecated in Python3.10).

The transition to Python3.10 for ROS2 Rolling happened only recently, and this is probably one of the issues that arose from it (but has not been fixed yet). Even if this does get fixed, it is unlikely the changes will be ported back to Foxy because the target platform for Foxy is Ubuntu20.04 which uses Python3.8 by default.

> /usr/lib/**python3.10**/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34:
> SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py
> install is deprecated. Use build and
> pip and other standards-based tools.

Your error message indicates that you're using Python3.10 to compile a ROS2 Foxy package. For this to happen, you must have manually installed Python3.10, installed a very recent version of Ubuntu (eg. 22.04), OR you're using a non-Ubuntu OS.

The recommended easy fix would be to revert to Python3.8 if you intend to use ROS2 Foxy.

I have raised an [issue about this in ament_cmake](https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake/issues/382)

---

Originally posted by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) with karma: 460 on 2022-03-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [waspinator](https://answers.ros.org/users/4020/waspinator/) on 2022-09-09**:
I'm not sure if this is strictly a Rolling issue. I see the same error on Humble.

**Comment by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) on 2022-09-09**:
You're right, at the time the question was posted, ROS 2 Humble wasn't yet released :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good day,
I just came across the same issue, following the ROS2  tutorial on python based services.
Reason I came across this post, I am facing the same issue and can confirm it is still a problem in ROS .
Here the info about my setup:

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

```
> Python 3.10.6 (main, Aug 10 2022,
> 11:40:04) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
> >>> import setuptools
> >>> print(setuptools.__version__)
> 59.6.0
> >>>
```

I will just continue for now and ignore this. Hopefully that's the best strategy and it will get addressed sometime soon

---

Originally posted by [PointCloud](https://answers.ros.org/users/73699/pointcloud/) with karma: 120 on 2022-09-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maxpol](https://answers.ros.org/users/110004/maxpol/) on 2022-10-27**:
Yup, I can confirm. Fresh Ubuntu 22.04 in Docker container hast this version of setuptools with the deprecation warning.